# Any established practices on overcoming the lack of multiple inheritance in Java?

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I have a classic diamond inheritance problem where

```
   A
 /   \
B     C
 \   /
   D
```

are all interfaces, and I have

```
AImpl(A)
|       \
|        \
BImpl(B)  CImpl(C)
|          \
|           \
DImpl(B,C)   \
|             F(C)
|
E(B,C)
```

where class `E` implements both interfaces `B` and `C`, but `F` implements only interface `C`.

Due to the lack of multiple inheritance, I currently have duplicated functionality in `DImpl` and `CImpl`.

I just fixed a bug in `CImpl`, but forgot to do the same for `DImpl`. Obviously remembering to always copy code from `CImpl` to `DImpl` and vice versa is not very sustainable as the code base keeps growing. Are there any established best practices for putting the shared code of both in a single place, despite the disallowance of multiple inheritance?

**EDIT** -- Solution with multiple inheritance would have been to have `DImpl` inherit `CImpl.cFunction()` instead of redefining `DImpl.cFunction` as a copy of `CImpl.cFunction`

**EDIT 2** -- Sample code:

```
public interface Animal {
  public void eat();
}

public interface FlyingAnimal extends Animal {
  public void fly();
}

public interface RunningAnimal extends Animal {
  public void run();
}

public interface Monster extends FlyingAnimal, RunningAnimal {
  public void roar();
}

public class AnimalImpl implements Animal {
  @Override
  public void eat() {
    ...
  }
}

public class FlyingAnimalImpl extends AnimalImpl implements FlyingAnimal {
  @Override
  public void fly() {
    ...
  }
}

public class RunningAnimalImpl extends AnimalImpl implements RunningAnimal {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    ...
  }
}

public class MonsterImpl extends FlyingAnimalImpl implements Monster {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void roar() {
    ...
  }
}

public class ScaryMonster extends MonsterImpl implements Monster {
  public void sneakAround() {
    ...
  }
}

public class Human extends RunningAnimalImpl implements RunningAnimal {
  public void scream() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now if I find a bug in `RunningAnimalImpl.run()` and I fix it, I have to remember to copy the fix over to `MonsterImpl.run()`.

Comment: What are A, B, C and D?

Comment: Are you sure your hierarchy is done correctly? It's impossible to tell with these generic names. What would be your solution if there was multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very poor design. You should not have a diamond structure in the first place just because it is possible in interfaces.

One of the basic principle of OOP is

**Prefer composition over inheritance!**

What I am saying is you don't need interface D at all. Wherever you need to use `DImpl` simply provide reference to `interface A` and then based on your runtime need pass `BIml` or `CImpl` instance to it. That way all you have to change is `BImpl` code or `CImpl` code for bug fix and it will be used anywhere you are using `DImpl` instance today.

As per your comment the code would be something like -

```
public class ScaryMonster {
  Animal animal;
  public  ScaryMonster(Animal animal) {
      this.animal = animal;
  }

  public void fly() {
      if(animal instanceof FlyingAnimal ) {
        ((FlyingAnimal )animal).fly();
      }
      else {
        throw new Exception("This mosnter cannot fly");
      }     
  }

  public void run() {
    if(animal instanceof RunningAnimal ) {
        ((RunningAnimal )animal).run();
      }
      else {
        throw new Exception("This mosnter cannot run");
      }
  }

  public void sneakAround() {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you want your monster to both fly and run pass instance of `MonsterImpl` to the constructor. Note now `ScaryMonster` does not extend or implement anything.

This is what I am saying - Prefer **composition over Inheritance!**.

Comment: Well `DImpl` still needs to implement `interface C` for those classes who want to work with only `C` objects. Though you're right that I can probably create an internal `CImpl` object within `DImpl` and pass my calls on to that

Comment: I am saying you don't need `D` or `DImpl` at all. Where ever you are using `Dimpl` or `D `replace it with `A` reference and at runtime pass `BImpl` or `CImpl` and invoke corresponding method.

Comment: Can you show me an example using classes from my examples above? Ultimately I do want a `ScaryMonster sm = new ScaryMonster();` that I can call both `sm.fly()` and `sm.run()` on without hassle

Comment: Have added a code snippet so you could understand this better. A lot of design patterns use this.

Comment: Yes but the problem still remains, how would I not duplicate code between `MonsterImpl.run()` and `RunningAnimalImpl.run()`? I need to construct a `MonsterImpl` first before I pass it to `ScaryMonster`'s constructor

Comment: Same logic. Your `MonsterImpl` should not extend `FlyingAnimalImpl ` rather should have a reference to `FlyingAnimalImpl ` instance and calling run on your `MonsterImpl` should call run on `FlyingAnimalImpl ` internally.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you can implement default methods within interfaces so if you have an interface with common implementations just define them inside of the interface and override them whenever you need to change it up a bit. Of course this is assuming you are using Java 8.

**For example:**

```
public interface A {
    default void cFunction(){
       System.out.println("Calling A.cFunction");
    }
}

public class DImpl implements A {
}
```

DImpl can call cFunction and it will default to calling the interfaces implementation.

In the case which 2 interfaces have a method with the same signature you can call them by referencing the interface name along with the method such as `A.super.cFunction()`

**More meaningful example:**

```
public interface Driveable {
    default void start(Vehicle vehicle){
       System.out.println("Starting my driveable thing");
       vehicle.mileage++;
    }
}


public interface Machine {
    default void start(){
       System.out.println("Starting my machine");
    }
}



public class ElectricCar extends Vehicle implements Driveable, Machine {
    public void start(){
       Driveable.super.start(this);
    }
}

public class DIYCar extends Vehicle implements Driveable, Machine {
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("instant fire");
    }
}
```

As you can see you can implement a default method in your interface and use it within your concrete class. In this scenario an ElectriCar is Driveable and a Machine but we want it to use the Driveable start() method because at the end of the day no matter how many machines (computers) are in our car, we still just want to drive it.

This is just an example and although the example may be a bit strange I hope it helps get the point across of being able to implement default methods.

**UPDATE for your example source:**

In your case of your Monster and Animal being able to run, you should have a RunnableCreature interface with an implementation of `run()`. This way if a Monster and Animal run the same they can reference the default `run()` method, otherwise it can override it and implement its own.

If you need your default method to manipulate variables two (or more) of your classes that have the same run() method would have common attributes and therefore should have a common base class. You can pass this base class to the default method and manipulate its variables as needed.

Comment: Good answer, and certainly gets the point across! But if the function needs to modify internal variables (e.g. calling `RunningAnimal.run()` depletes energy or calling `Machine.start()` sets `boolean machineIsOn;` to true), then this approach won't work, right?

Comment: You can use a method argument to pass in the base object you are looking to manipulate. For example, if all of your RunnableCreatures are creatures you can pass a Creature as an argument: run(Creature c){ c.energy--; }

Comment: I have updated my answer showing how you can pass your own instance to the method to manipulate variables. Hope it gives you some insight into a possible option.

Answer (score 1):

Don't implement C in D, instead of inheritance compose it within D. In that way you dont duplicate your code and have just one implementation of C.

If you somehow needs to inherit from C (which i think you would need to review design then), then i would still suggest you compose C and implement all the methods of C within D and delegate calls via composed object.

Answer (score 1):

A common alternative would be to use composition instead of inheritance. Does it make sense to say that `D` **is a** `B` and **is also a** `C`? Does `D` really need to expose **every** public method contained in `B` and `C`? If the answer to any of these questions is no, then inheritance is not the right tool for the job.

If you want to read further about the advantages of composition, check this chapter from Effective Java: [Favor composition over inheritance](http://jtechies.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/item-16-favor-composition-over.html)

Comment: I believe the answer to both questions would be yes in my case, but good to know, thanks!